# How to set up Ubuntu for multiple users at the same time?

Tags: multi-user

I'm still kinda new to linux and my understanding was I could let multiple people (at the most me + two more) use my pc at the same time. If this is indeed the case, how do I?

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is called "multiseat", and you need to set it up to work that way. The instructions are here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX

Comment: could it be the answer of "How to set up Ubuntu for multiple users at the same time **on the same pc**?" ?

Comment: I agree this question is ambiguous and needs clarification.