# two people to use the same computer

Tags: users, 23.04

I have an Ubuntu 23.04 computer. My wife and I work in different areas, so I would like to know if it is possible to split the computer into two users with different screens and keyboards using the same machine so that our files do not come together while we can work at the same time.

I saw that ltsp was an alternative, but apparently it doesn't support using the server as a client (this is the case). I know absolutely nothing about this. I've seen that Xorg does something similar, but I don't understand anything at all.

Comment: Have a look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/277992/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-for-multiple-users-at-the-same-time